# Find a QGIS 3.16 installer for MacOS

Tags: qgis

I moved from **3.16** to **3.22** lately and I am experiencing **zoom glitches** that make it really hard to use QGIS. I want to move back to version 3.16 which worked smoothly but can not find an installation/dmg file. Does anyone have a lead to it?

I could only find this:
https://www.kyngchaos.com/software/archive/qgis/
and I don't know if I can trust it.

Comment: Maybe here: [https://download.qgis.org/downloads/macos/](https://download.qgis.org/downloads/macos/)

Comment: It doesn't seem to exist in their archive, There is a gap (or, I couldn't find it there). Thanks though (:

Comment: https://download.qgis.org/downloads/macos/ltr/qgis_ltr_final-3_16_6_20210428_160530.dmg

Comment: Yes, Thanks! I guess I didnt look at all these folders ):